# ssh-add id_rsa.pub generating invalid format error

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, ssh-keys

Following a tutorial on ssh, and successfully generated an ssh key pair (public & private) using `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "demo pubkey"`
,

The next step taken by the instructor was to start the ssh program in the background using `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`.

Then next instruction was to add the ssh key using `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`.

The instructors command ran successfully but my says **invalid format** when i `ssh-add <the id_rsa.pub file>`, but successfully adds when i `ssh-add <the id_rsa file>`.

I am very new to this, and I have -0 idea whats going, anyone?

**The id_rsa file looks like**

```
    -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

**The id_rsa.pub file looks like**

```
ssh-rsa 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 demo pubkey
```

Comment: You've posted your private credentials on a public website. Make sure you delete these id_rsa and id_rsa.pub files from your machine, and remove the public key from github or any other place that you copied it to so that this key no longer works.

Comment: No they are fake, typed them my self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ssh-agent`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-agent) is an authentication agent used for verifying a user/computer using asymmetric cryptography.
The private key is "your identity" and the public key can be used to "verify" your identity. So, the private key should be known to the authentication agent (ssh-agent in your case), while the public key will be used by the remote service/server. ssh-agent only needs to know private key and not the public key.